# How to calculate system idle time in Ubuntu on Wayland?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, wayland

I've implemented the below code to calculate system idle time in ubuntu on xorg which is working fine:-

```
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xinerama.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

 uint getSystemIdleTime()
 {
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    if (!dpy) {
        return(0);
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    XScreenSaverInfo *info = XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
    XScreenSaverQueryInfo(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), info);
    uint idletime= info->idle / 1000;
    XFree(info);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return idletime;
}

int main()
{  
    int ans = getSystemIdleTime();
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

but I'm unable to find any method/API to calculate system idle in ubuntu on Wayland.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120957/run-a-command-when-system-is-idle-and-when-is-active-again

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but the answer you have attached works for xorg only but not in wayland,  which is what I want.